# Criar nova matriz a partir de uma primeira bastante grande de forma eficiente

Tags: r, matriz, data.frame

Caros, em R, eu tenho uma base de dados muito grande e quero criar novas colunas. Vou tentar explicar meu problema com uma matriz bem pequena. A seguir, "1" significa escola particular e "2", publica. Tenho por exemplo uma base de dados

```
>Data
Casa Escola 
 1     1
 1     1
 1     2
 1     2
 2     1
 2     2
 2     1
 3     1
 3     1
 3     1
 3     1
```

Nese caso, concluímos que a casa 1 tem 4 moradores que estão na escola, sendo 2 em particular e 2 em pública. Analogamente, a casa 2 tem 3 moradores em escola, 2 em particular e 1 em publica. Finalmente, a casa 3 tem 4 pessoas na escola e todas em particular.

Eu quero  uma nova matiz com a primeira coluna indicando a casa; a segunda indicando o número de crianças na casa ; a terceira indicando o número das que estão em escola particular e  Finalmente, a quarta, indicando o numero de crianças em escola pública. Algo assim:

```
  >matrix1
  >   Casa    em_escola     part     publ
       1          4          2        2
       2          3          2        1
       3          4          4        0
```

Eu fiz um código que mostrarei a seguir. O problema deste código é que a minha matriz original é muito grande e demora horas para rodar. Além disso, preciso fazer a mesma coisa para outras matrizes. A seguir, meu código

```r
lista1<- unique(Data$Casa)
length(lista1)
n=length(lista1)

lista_aux<- c(1:n)


matrix1<- data.frame(lista_aux,lista1)
nrow(matrix1)


for(i in 1:n) 
{


matrix = subset(Data , control_uc == lista1[i] )
matrix1$em_escola[i] <- nrow(matrix)

mat1<- subset (matrix, Escola == "1" )
matrix1$part[i]<- nrow(mat1)

mat2<- subset(matrix, cod_freq_escola =="2" )
matrix1$publ[i]<- nrow(mat2)
}
```

matrix1 é a matriz que eu quero... Mas como eu disse, preciso de um código bem mais rápido do que isso.. pois demora muito na hora de rodar em  base de dados muito grande

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar a biblioteca [dplyr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html) para tornar seu código mais simples e, ao mesmo tempo, mais eficiente:

```r
library(dplyr)

Data <- data.frame(Casa=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
    Escola=c(1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1))

matrix1 <- Data %>%
    group_by(Casa) %>%
    summarise(em_escola = n(),
        part = sum(Escola == 1),
        publ = sum(Escola == 2))

matrix1
```

Comment: E se a minha base de dados Data tiver outra coluna chamada "peso"?.  Suponha que cada casa tenha um peso... como faço para manter essa coluna na minha nova matriz?

Comment: Nesse caso você pode fazer `group_by(Casa, peso)`.

Comment: Só por curiosidade... o que significa "em escola = n()" ?

Comment: Na verdade, quero saber qual é o papel do "n( )"

Comment: `n()` conta o número de linhas em cada grupo. É específico do dplyr.

Answer (score 5):

Para complementar, deixo também uma resposta com o [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html). Tanto o dplyr quanto o data.table são extremamente rápidos para grandes base de dados. O dplyr é, na minha opinião, mais intuitivo e o data.table é mais flexível.

```r
library(data.table)
Data <- data.table(Data)
matrix1 <- Data[,list(em_escola = length(Escola),
           part=sum(Escola==1),
           publ = sum(Escola==2)), by=Casa]
```

Comment: E se a minha base de dados Data tiver outra coluna chamada "peso"?.  Suponha que cada casa tenha um peso... como faço para manter essa coluna na minha nova matriz?

Comment: Se o peso é uma variável pela qual você quer agrupar, você coloca no final, com o by, `by=list(Casa, peso)`. Se o peso é uma variável que você quer sumarizar por casa, por exemplo, peso médio, você adiciona no list do meio `list(em_escola = length(Escola),
           part=sum(Escola==1),
           publ = sum(Escola==2),peso_medio = mean(peso))`

Comment: ainda nesta questão, usando o data.table, como eu faço para criar uma variável dependendo de um subconjunto de outra? Por exemplo, usando dplyr, na hora de sumarizar, podemos fazer algo assim: novacol = fun(variavel1[variavel2 == "A"]), ou seja, estou aplicando a funcao fun na variável 1 restringida a elementos onde variavel2 = A